# NullPointerException when accessing image files in a .jar file

Tags: java, jar, classpath

I have pretty much tried everything but still have this same problem. I have the following setup: I have a images.jar containing a folder called 'images' in which there are multiple image files. I add images.jar to the java build path of the project in eclipse, and i've been trying to use the following code to access the individual images in the jar:

```
URL url = this.getClass().getResource("images/a.png");
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon (url);
```

Unfortunately, the URL object is always NULL. I don't think this has anything to do with where I put images.jar file as it is added to the classpath in eclipse. I have also tried using the path '/images/a.png', but still the same problem. Any suggestion would be extremely welcome! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("images/a.png");
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(url);
```

Without `getClassLoader()` invocation you are only able to access resources in JAR file where the code is stored.

Comment: First, the poster already tried getResource("/images/a.png"), which is strictly equivalent to what you've suggested.  Second, Class.getResource() has no additional "same JAR" restriction than ClassLoader.getResource (Class.getResource typically delegates to ClassLoader.getResource).  However, you are correct that if a security manager is installed, there could be a permission problem with cross-JAR access.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't reproduce your problem, but my theory is that you are running the class from a different place than you think you are -- that the image and the class are in different jars, or the class is read directly from the class file.

Comment: The class that is trying to load the image is inside a package in the src folder of the project. Is there any way I can verify what you've suggested above?

Comment: It sounds like you are using Maven or something to build the jar.  Track down the jar you are building (it will probably be in the target/ directory) and use "jar tvf target/thefileyourebuildin.jar" .  This will print out a list that *should* include both the class you are trying to run and "images/a.png" .  If it doesn't (and my guess is that it won't), you have to wrestle with mvn or whatever you're using until it does.